# xDB Xconnect.Contact returning null value

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I am working with xDB code upgrade from Sitecore 8.2 to 9.3 xconnect. I'm using the below code in 8.2 to get current contact and it returning contact value.

```
Public Contact Getcurrentcontact()
{ 
 return Tacker.Current.Session.Contact 
}
```

To do the same in Sitecore 9.3 I am using the below code to get contact by contact id but it always returns the null value.

```
public Contact GetCurrentContact()
{
    if (Tracker.IsActive && Tracker.Current != null && Tracker.Current.Session != null)
    {
        Contact contact = null;
        Guid identifier = Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId;
        ContactReference reference = new ContactReference(identifier);
        using (XConnectClient client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            contact = client.Get<Contact>(reference,
                new ContactExpandOptions(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey,
                    EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey));
        }

        return contact;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: Do you use your code in any of Sitecore (pre?)request pipelines or in the code of your rendering controller? Do you have `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled`? Which of conditions return false for you? Is that contact a returning contact or a new one? Doesn't `Tracker.Current.Contact` contain what you need?

Comment: Xdb is enabled and I'm calling this function in rendering controller. It is returning contact

Comment: And why do you try to get contact from `XConnectClient`? Isn't what you have in `Tracker.Current.Contact` enough?

Comment: I need xconnect contact. If I'm using Tracker.current.Contact I'm getting cannot implicitly convert type Sitecore. Analytics.tracking.contact to Sitecore.Xconnect.Contact

Comment: And how do you identify your contact in the first place? Is it anonymous user? or a known one?

Comment: In the first place I am identifying contact by using Account.user name

Comment: Please update your question with textual representation of code not screenshot. It's impossible to crawl this question for crawlers properly otherwise. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code which should work for you:

```
private Contact GetExistingXConnectContact()
{
    if (!Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.IsNew)
    {
        var anyIdentifier = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.FirstOrDefault();

        if (anyIdentifier != null)
        {
            using (XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration
                .SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    return client.Get(
                        new IdentifiedContactReference(anyIdentifier.Source, anyIdentifier.Identifier),
                        new ContactExpandOptions(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey));
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    // handle exc
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

You can find more in Sitecore documentation, e.g. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/set-contact-facets-in-session.html

Answer (score 1):

Reference of the Contact should be the same, it should not be like one variable created from `Sitecore.Analytics.tracking.contact`  and another is from `Sitecore.Xconnect.Contact`

From the above inline comments, I can say your code line `Contact contact=null;` is taking reference from a different DLL. Could you please change the assignment with

```
Sitecore.XConnect.Contact contact = null;
```

In my opinion, it's taking reference from the `Sitecore.Analytics.tracking.contact`, you can hover on variable and check the reference details.